# jquery.inputmask.js not returning unmasked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I'm using the **5.0.2** version of j**query.inputmask.js** on an asp.net MVC project. I have a simple input text field called "Cellphone" that comes with the user's phone number already filled, loaded from Razor:

```
<input value="00000000000" class="form-control " id="Cellphone" name="Cellphone" type="text" inputmode="text">
```

On the user's side, when document.ready is called I set-up the mask by using:

```
$("#Cellphone").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "(99) 99999-9999" });
```

But, if I try to call the unmask function `$("#Cellphone").inputmask('unmaskedvalue')` right away via browser console, I simply get the masked value `"(00) 00000-0000"` instead of the unmasked one `"000000000"`.

Stranger still, if I erase all the information from the field and simply type in the value `"00000000000"` with the keyboard and call the unmask function via console it will return the proper unmasked value.

On a previous version of the project I was using the **4.0.9** version and I did not have this problem.

Am I doing something wrong with the mask setup?

Why does the unmasked function return the unmasked value only if I type in manually?